# JavaScript: disable <button> until value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, selection

I'm trying to implement a javascript code for the html5 form that will responsible for disabling/enabling the button until the select element is not selected. Here is the codes:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="courseForm" id="courseForm">
    <select name="coursetype" id="coursetype" onchange="enableStartBtn()">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select here...</option>
        <option value="1">CourseName 1</option>
        <option value="2">CourseName 2</option>
        <option value="3">CourseName 3</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" id="startBtn" disabled="disabled" onclick="Test()">Start</button>
</form>
```

and **JavaScript**:

```
function enableStartBtn() {
    $('#startBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}

function Test() {
    var form = $('#courseForm');
    var course = $('#coursetype', form).val();
    if (course == '0') {
        alert('Select the course first!');
    } else if (course == '1') {
        alert('CourseName 1 is selected!');
    } else if (course == '2') {
        alert('CourseName 2 is selected!');
    } else if (course == '3') {
        alert('This course is not implemented yet');
    }
}
```

I'm using **JQuery 1.9.1** in my code, everything looks like ok, but the when value is selected the button is not enables. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Sorry guys forgot to mention that I'm also using **JQuery Mobile 1.3.0**, so without including jquery mobile it works, but with jquery mobile not.
Here is the jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/dozent/UVQ4m/

Comment: use `.prop('disabled',false)` to enable

Comment: It works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/JMkRa/ , although I do agree you should use `prop` for this

Comment: You can also add "disabled" to your <option> markup so the user can't re-select this: `<option value="0" selected="selected" disabled>`

Comment: If you're trying to toggle it being disabled (based on the selected item), you could use this: http://jsfiddle.net/JMkRa/2/ . It uses a special `data-*` attribute to target not implemented courses, instead of storing that in the JS

Comment: @lan Please have a look to `update` part of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form name="courseForm" id="courseForm">
    <select name="coursetype" id="coursetype">
        <option value="0" disabled>Select here...</option>
        <option value="1">CourseName 1</option>
        <option value="2">CourseName 2</option>
        <option value="3">CourseName 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="startBtn" disabled>Start</button>
</form>
```

And do :

```
var courses = ['1','2']; // available courses

$('#coursetype').one('change', function() {
     $('#startBtn').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#startBtn').on('click', function() {
    var val = $('#coursetype').val(),
        msg = $.inArray(val, courses) != -1 ? 'CourseName '+val+' is selected!' : 'This course is not implemented yet';
    alert(msg);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KXF8/)

Comment: Nice. Although maybe it makes sense to just put a special `data-*` attribute on the "not implemented" courses. Also, why are you using `.one()`?

Comment: Why `.one()`?  Wouldn't it be better to enable/disable the button according to course availability?

Comment: Once the select is changed, the button is enabled, and you can't select the first option again, so there's no need to execute the event handler more than once.

Comment: But I wouldn't want the button enabled if the course were not available.  I would disable it if the user selects course 3. I suppose that's a UI issue, though.

Comment: @DerekHenderson - I would probably do something like that as well, but then you don't need a button, you'd do everything in the change event, as there's no need for a button to tell you if the course is available if the button is disabled when the course is unavailable ? Anyway, the question was to enable the button on the first change of the select, and having the event handler for more than one time is unesseccary !

Comment: @adeneo, point taken.  Of course, no answer is necessary, as the OP's code works just fine.  ;)

Comment: @adeneo have you tried your solution with JQuery Mobile 1.3.0?

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying to include this code to my phonegap app and for mobile view I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.0 supposed that newest version of jquery mobile is without bugs.

Comment: jQuery mobile changes the game entirely, it has it's own event handlers, and rebuild select drop downs with custom UI elements and other stuff, so that's not even close to the answers posted here.

Answer (score 1):

use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
function enableStartBtn() {
   $('#startBtn').prop('disabled',false); //<----to remove  disable attr of the button
}
```

you need to change the property of the button here not just remove the attribute

Answer (score 0):

include in header area

1. not this =$('#coursetype').one('change', function() {
2. it should=  $('#coursetype').on('change', function() {